# Strange error highlighting 'instance method cannot override the static method' in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

Assume I have such code in Groovy:

```
class Base {
   static String name = 'base';
}

class Child extends Base {
 String name = 'child';

 static main(args){
    def ch = new Child();
    println ch.name;
 }

}
```

Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 highlights that there is an error:

> This instance method cannot override the static method from Base

I don't override any static methods and it executes as I expect, so what does Eclipse think is wrong?

Comment: Where is it reported?

Answer (score 0):

The error message could be improved because what you're doing here isn't related to a method (unless Eclipse is considering the methods in the generated Java), it's related to a variable. Also, Groovy doesn't really care about this so the code works, but Java wouldn't like it.

Eclipse is letting you know that you are defining an instance variable in `Child` that has the same name as a static variable in `Base`.

You should have a static modifier in both classes.

```
class Child extends Base {
    static String name = 'child'
    //...
}
```